# Run a SQL query on existing recordset?

Tags: excel, ado, sql, recordset, vba

I've created a 3rd recordset (disconnected) from two existing recordsets that came from different connections.

Now, I'd like to run a SQL query on this 3rd recordset.

I am using Excel VBA.

thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ADO RecordSet Filter method with SQL where clauses: [Filter and RecordCount Properties Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681465(VS.85).aspx), e.g.

```
rs.Filter = "SupplierID = 10"
```